# HTTP POST in java throws an error - no suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class

Tags: java, api, http-post, url-parameters

I have a java process which is listening to ActiveMQ messages and when the status is COMPLETE, I am calling HTTP POST as shown in the code below. I'm referring to the [following 
article](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) for sending POST(). However, I'm running into following issue:

In the eclipse console, I am getting the following error:

```
Testing 1 - Send Http POST request
{"timestamp":"2020-05-15T01:00:59.232+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failed : No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class com.abc.tpms.mxnf.entities.DataDeliveryAction from request with content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8!","path":"/CompanyServices/api/dataDeliveryActions"}
```

When I used POSTMAN, the request worked fine but I had to make following changes in the POSTMAN (as shown in the screenshot below - encircled in red).

1) Put my parameters inside Body section of POSTMAN

2) Changed the type to JSON.

[image]

**My relevant code below:**

```
// All imports goes here

@Component
public class DownloadConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    // one instance, reuse
    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    // Working Code with JMS 2.0
    @JmsListener(destination = "MessageProducer")
        public void processBrokerQueues(String message) throws DaoException {



            System.out.println("Message Retrieved is:" +message);
            try {

            RequestDao requestDao = (RequestDao) context.getBean("requestDao");

            String receivedStatus = requestDao.getRequestStatus(message);

            //Before sending this message, do the check for COMPLETE or ERROR etc
            if(receivedStatus.equals("COMPLETE")) {




                /*****************************************************\
                    // START: Calling webservices

                  *******************************************************/

                 DownloadConsumer obj = new DownloadConsumer();

                    try {


                        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http POST request");
                        obj.sendPost();
                    } finally {
                        obj.close();
                    }

            }
            else {





            }

            }
            catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();   

            }

         }




    private void close() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }

    private void sendPost() throws Exception {


       HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://myservername.com/CompanyServices/api/dataDeliveryActions");

        // add request parameter, form parameters
        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestId", "123456"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("projectId", "71"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assetId", "4"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assetName", "Test at PM By User"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
             CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)) {

            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }

    }





    // URL of the JMS server. DEFAULT_BROKER_URL will just mean that JMS server is on localhost
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String subject = "MessageProducer"; //Queue Name
    // default broker URL is : tcp://localhost:61616"

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadConsumer.class);



}
```

What am I doing wrong inside the `sendPost()` method while calling HTTP POST? Do I need to take care of JSON thing just like I did in POSTMAN. If yes, then how? Please advise. Thanks !

**EDIT [Testing Results after referring Ananthapadmanabhan's answer]**

This time I didn't get any error but the record didn't get inserted into the database. The following is what I got in my eclipse after printing response.

```
  Testing 1 - Send Http POST request
Printing Response in Eclipse HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401  [Date: Fri, 15 May 2020 15:23:31 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.6 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma: no-cache, Expires: 0, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains, X-Frame-Options: DENY, Content-Type: application/json, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100, Connection: Keep-Alive, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Chunked: true]}}
```

And here is my modified method that I used this time:

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {


         HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://myservername.com/CompanyServices/api/dataDeliveryActions");


        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("details={\"requestId\":\"123456\",\"projectId\":\"71\",\"assetId\":\"4\",\"assetName\":\"test at AM by User\"} ");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.setEntity(params);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Printing Response in Eclipse "+response);
        //assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(200));
        httpClient.close();

     }
```

**Question:**

1) What wrong I might be doing?
2) Is it mandatory to specify `details` in the json string? I noticed that if I didn't do that eclipse complains about deleting tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my observation , I could understand that in your postman call , you are sending the post request with `application/json` as the `content-type` and a json in the request body , which is working fine. But in your code , you are setting it like :

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

try setting the content type as `application/json` in your code as well for the post request instead of url-encoded one and it should work.For sending json I think you should use the `StringEntity` class. You could create a pojo class to map the data to be in the request and then use a json library like Gson to convert it to the appropriate format or you could do it manually like for example like:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://yoururl");
StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"name\":\"myname\",\"age\":\"20\"} ");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

//handle response here...
```

[Link](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request)

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post with testing results.Could you take a look? The record doesn't seem to get inserting for some reason.

Comment: @Tan Are there any authorization header that sis needed to be added to the request ?  The response code that you receive now is 401 which is Unauthorized access , please check your postman headers to verify and add it to your code.

Comment: Problem was this : `StringEntity params =new StringEntity("details={\"name\":\"myname\",\"age\":\"20\"} ");`. When I changed it to `StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"name\":\"myname\",\"age\":\"20\"} ");`, it worked fine and I got 201 message. May I know why `details` was included in the string by you? Thanks !

Comment: @Tan Oh sorry I added it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json String to pass to Your API. Then call the below function with your JSON String and URL.

```
public JSONObject httpPOSTClient(String json, String url) {
    JSONObject jobj = null;
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
      HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
      StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json);
      request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
      request.setEntity(params);
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
      String res = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
      jobj = new JSONObject(res);
      org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return jobj;
  }
```

It will first send the Request to the API, setting all the necessary parameters. It will then accept a String response in "res", which IF NEEDED can be converted to JSONObject type.

Comment: Hope it helps :)